# jQuery sound on keydown

Tags: jquery, audio, keydown

first question on Stack Overflow. I've searched for my problem but couldn't find an answer.

I'm trying to get 30 seconds of a song to play when I press down and hold a certain key but I can't get it to work. I want the song to start playing when I hold down the key and stop playing when I let go of the key. I tried to recreate the problem I'm having on JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Z2UuR/

```
$(document).keydown(function(){
if(event.keyCode == 88) {
playBlurredLines();
console.log("A key was pressed");
$(".one").css('background-color', 'blue'); 
}
})
.keyup(function(){
$(".one").css('background-color', 'orange'); 
});

function playBlurredLines() {
$('#blurred-lines')[0].volume = 0.5;
$('#blurred-lines')[0].load();
$('#blurred-lines')[0].play();
}
```

The song plays fine when you tap 'X' but when I hold down 'X', nada! Any help is much appreciated.

P.S. Sorry for the Blurred Lines audio clip.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass `event` to your `keydown` function:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 88) {
```

Comment: Thanks Felix. I actually did have that in my original code. Just missed it when I was setting up the JSFiddle. Even with the event passed to the keydown function, I still get the same problem. Clip won't play on hold down of the X key. Only plays when you quickly tap X.